# Use of undefined constant fileError

Tags: php, file-upload

Use of undefined constant fileError - assumed 'fileError' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\upload.php on line 17
There was an error uploading your files

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $FileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

if(in_array($FileActualExt, $allowed)){
if(fileError === 0){
if ($fileSize < 500000000){
$FileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$FileActualExt;
$FileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
header('Location: index.php?uploadsuccess');    
} else {
echo "Your file was too big";
}   
} else {
 echo "There was an error uploading your files";
}   
} else {
echo "You can't upload files of this type"; 
}
}
?>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
```

What's the proper code to solve the error?

Comment: Fixed, logic don't work Any solutions?

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Simple issue of improper names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
if(fileError === 0){
```

to

```
if($fileError === 0){
```